# query hbase row-key

Tags: sql, hadoop, hbase

can I query hbase to get all rows which row-key start with some string

something like scan 'Table_Name' 'ram%'

I want to get all rows that row-key starts with ram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `PrefixFilter` to get rowkey's matching a specified prefix

```rb
hbase> scan 'TABLE_NAME', { FILTER => "PrefixFilter('ram')"}
```

Above statement in hbase shell will give you all the rowkey's that start with 'ram'.

From Java API you try this:

```java
byte[] prefix=Bytes.toBytes("ram");
Scan scan = new Scan(prefix));
PrefixFilter prefixFilter = new PrefixFilter(prefix);
scan.addFilter(prefixFilter);
ResultScanner resultScanner = table.getScanner(scan);
```

Comment: thanks it works. Can I write the same using Java? do you have any example program?